# Ruby: Passing a Proc to method with no parameters

Tags: ruby

So this works(Pulled from Code-Academy):

```
def greeter
  yield
end

phrase = Proc.new {
  puts "Hello there!"
  }

greeter(&phrase)
```

I understand what yield is doing, and understand what a Proc does. However "why" is this allowed?

IE: `greeter` method has no parameters defined, not even optional ones. So why does ruby allow us to pass something to it? (In this case a reference to a block of code (The Proc `phrase`).

I mean it's great that it does, but rule-wise this seems like it shouldn't be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&phrase` is not a reference. It is the Ruby annotation for passing a block explicitly. Here , it is converting the proc to the implicit block for the method call. Since every method accepts a default block as an argument, your code works.

Comment: "Since every method accepts a default block as an argument, your code works." - I think since Im still new to ruby I didn't realize this. So you can always pass 1 block to a method? (I guess that makes sense, since we pass blocks to stuff like "map" and "collect" etc...). Can they accept more than 1 block by default out of curiosity?

Comment: @msmith1114 No. More than 1 block would cause ambiguity as to which block to yield to and thus raises a `Syntax` error. Methods can only receive 1 explicit block as well e.d `def some_method(&block);end` however you can pass as many block like objects (e.g. `Proc`, `lambda`, etc.) as the method arity will support

Comment: @engineersmnky Sorry maybe Im confused, your saying I can pass as many Procs/Lambdas as I want as parameters, but I can only pass one block to a method that's explicity defined like `{whatever}`?

Comment: @msmith1114, that is correct. You can think of `Proc`s, `lambda`s and `block`s to be blocks of code that can be passed around. Every `method`, be default, allows an optional block to be passed to it. Since `Proc`s and `lambda`s can be named, you can pass around more than one. Check [this example](https://gist.github.com/rahulrajaram/07191625d36e9f3a946cf59a97b0ca60) I created out.